# What is $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is probably a pretty dumb question, but I am confused by set theory again. The question is whether 
$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$$
equals $[0,1]$ or $[0,1)$. However, I am looking for some explanation and not only the result, since I'd like to understand why it's the one or the other.

Comment: The element $1$ is in the union iff it is in one of the sets.

Comment: But $1 \in \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [0,1-\frac{1}{n}]$ isn't it? Or does the limit make no sence here anyway?

Comment: In a way, the union above is the way of defining such a limit. But your notation does not make sense. You just need to treat the union as you treat finite unions.

Comment: @Haatschii: I can't think of a notion of limit for sequences of sets that would make $1$ a member of that limit.

Comment: There will be some numbers in the union that are within (say) $0.1$ of $1$, also some numbers in the union which are within $0.00001$ of $1$, and so on. But there is no number in your union which is **exactly** equal to $1$.

Comment: @Henning: What about the notion "$1$ is in every limit of a sequence of sets!"? :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Okay, then "any _reasonable_ notion of limit". Where "reasonable" requires, among other things, that limits commute with any bijection with a sufficiently large domain, and that a constant sequence is its own limit.

Comment: @Haatschii: Is there a reason you un-accepted my answer? If something is not clear or complete, please let me know.

Comment: @Henning: considering your side question, if you were working in, say, the lattice of *closed* subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then the limit — specifically, the supremum — of that sequence would be [0,1].  While this certainly isn’t something than can be defined on subsets of arbitrary sets, and doesn’t commute with general bijections etc., it’s a pretty reasonable notion of limit for sequences of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: The comment at Robert Mastragostino answer confused me again. But I think now I got the idea...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remember that $x\in\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_i$ if and only if for some $i\in I$, $x\in A_i$.

So $1$ is in the union if and only if it appears in at least on of those intervals, so is it? No. It is not.

---

To the comment, don't think of $\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty$ as a limit in the calculus-sense of the word. Think of it as a logical operation which tells you that the index set is $\mathbb N$ (or some other set which is clear from context) and then use the above formula.

If you wish to think about it as $f(n)=\bigcup\limits_{k=1}^n [0,1-\frac1k]$, and think about the infinite union as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(n)$, then there are several caveats:

1. Limits will usually require some sort of topology, some underlying structure which tells us about convergence. How would you define the limit here? For every $\varepsilon>0$...? It makes no sense, since subsets of $\mathbb R$ do not have a natural metric function.
2. We can consider the following definition: $A$ is the limit of the sequence of $f(n)$ if and only if for every $x\in A$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n>n_0$, $x\in A_n$.

   Observe, however, that this coincides with the definition above, that $x$ is in the union if and only if it appears in at least one of the functions. This definition, however, coincides with the above **only** because this sequence of sets is increasing.
3. Luckily, we can always think of an infinite union as an increasing sequence, but we would expect a definition for a limit to work for *any* sequence of sets, not just increasing unions.
4. We *can*, however, think of it as a limit of a sequence of characteristic functions, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_{\left[0,1-\frac1n\right]}=\chi_{[0,1)}$$
   even as such limit, though, it is not "continuous" in the way you would like it to be, that is, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_{\left[0,1-\frac1n\right]}\neq\chi_{\left[0,1-\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\right]}$$

Comment: I will have to think about it for a while, but I hope I got the right idea of what is going on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Haatschii: Glad I could help. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 15):

1 is not in any of the sets, so it can't be in their union.

Answer (score 9):

The whole point of a limit is that you go "up to but not including" the number. The limit of the upper bound of the union you gave is $1$, but that doesn't mean $1$ is in the union. Just like saying $\lim_{x\to 2}f(x)=3$ doesn't imply $f(2)=3$. To be an element of the union, it must be in at least one set. If you can't pick any single set  (pre-union) that contains $1$, then it isn't in the union. It *is* a limit point, which is where the confusion lies, but that's a different thing entirely.

Comment: +1: An excellent analogy! And considering $f:\Bbb N\to\mathcal{P}(\Bbb R)$ given by $$f(n)=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n+1}\left[0,1-\frac 1 k\right],$$ we're looking at just such a situation.

Comment: @CameronBuie: So to get things rights. Am I right that using this $f(n)$, follows $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} = [0,1] \neq [0,1) = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[ 0, 1- \frac{1}{k} \right]$$? Is this what you mean with this $\bigcup _{n=1}^\infty$ being different than a "normal" limit?

Comment: @Haatschii: Limits talk about continuity. This simply tells you that the union is *not* a continuous function. Similarly you can consider a cardinal function, $n\mapsto|\mathcal P(\{0,\ldots,n\})|$. The limit is the cardinality of finite subsets of $\mathbb N$ which is $\aleph_0$, but $f("\infty")$ is uncountable.

Comment: @Haatschii that sort of union *is* a normal limit. Or rather, it can be construed as one under the right circumstances (feel free to think of it as one, basically). The point we're making is that "$x$ is a limit point of a set" isn't the same as "$x$ is in the set". It *is* a normal limit, but like normal limits it doesn't (have to) actually take the value it approaches.

Answer (score -1):

Note that, for this case, (with the "definition" of $\infty$ expanded)

$$\begin{aligned}
\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right] & \stackrel{\operatorname{def}}{=} \lim_{k\to\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^k \left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right] \\
 & = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left[0,1-\frac{1}{k}\right] \\
 & = \left[0,1\right)
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: What do you mean by $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right]$? Without further explanation, the notation $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ is reserved, at least for me, for limits of sequences of real or complex numbers.

Comment: In this case, it just means the union is equal to the last member.

Comment: The expression "the last member" is a bit unfortunate, since this terminology suggests that the union is only over a finite, totally ordered set. Also your answer seems to hide away the essential points which explain why $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \left[0,1-\frac{1}{n}\right] = \left[0,1\right)$. For example, why is it not $[0,1]$?

Comment: Courtesy of `\stackrel{}{}`.

Comment: I've expanded out the $\infty$. That shows my understanding of "last". As far as [0,1) instead of [0,1], I understand the former to be the only logical answer; other answers have gone into it further. I suppose my simple answer is like the top answer, the interval never actually contains 1, and because we have a symbol for it [0,1) is the answer. Note it is the fact that it is a one-sided limit: the simple $\lim_{n\to1}[0,n]=[0,1]$, but $\lim_{n\to1 \text{from below}}[0,n]=[0,1)$